# Display data from many to many relationship in windows form using LINQ

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I have three tables stored in my database: `Speaker`, `Language`, and `link_speaks`. All three of them have multiple attributes. `link_speaks` is used to connect the `Speaker` to `Language` "many to many" - relationship. The primary/foreign key relations are defined in the sql database.

Table information: 
[image]

I would like a windows form to display the information in `Speaker` for every entry plus a table of the languages he/she speaks, taken from the other two tables.

The result would look a lot [like this](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/wriju/WindowsLiveWriter/LINQtoSQLWindowsFormBindingDataStepbySte_12506/image_2.png) (taken from [this tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2007/11/02/linq-to-sql-windows-form-binding-data-step-by-step.aspx) I found)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Pleas provide the definition of your tables and let us know what exactly want to display (which columns)

Comment: @Christos like this? http://i.imgur.com/uzqqlFc.png

Answer (score 0):

Set the binding navigator on the main page to have the datasource as the entire tbl_Personen.
Then set the bindingsource on the datagridview to that person objects related person's language...

Here's some kinda code to do the first part (it's not perfect, but you get the general idea):

```
using (var data = yourdataentities())
{
   var person = data.Personen.FirstOrDefault();
   formbindingsource.DataSource = person;
   var languagesGuySpeaks = from p_x_l in data.link_spricht
                            join language in data.Sprachen on language.Id equals p_x_l.SprachID
                            where p_x_l.Person_ID == person.Id
                            select language;


   datagridbindingsource.DataSource = languagesGuySpeaks;
}
```

Then add an event handler to update datagridbindingsource.DataSource when your person changes (however you want to handle that; like a dropdown or whatever)